# PHP script is timing out

Tags: php, domdocument

I am pulling data from a page and I know this is a long process depending on the date being pulled. After 132 seconds of pulling the data the page times-out.
I have set the set_time_limit(0);and ignore_user_abort(true); - I am not sure what else to do to keep the script alive and pull all the data.

I have added the code below in case there is something i can do to speed it up??

```
 set_time_limit(0);
    ignore_user_abort(true);
    error_reporting(-1);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
    include "../include/class.php";
    include "../include/db.php";
    //the below will get the list of id's for each race that day

    function curl($url){
                $ch = curl_init();
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
                curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,true);
                $data = curl_exec($ch);
                curl_close($ch);
                return $data;
      }





    $url  = "http://form.timeform.betfair.com/daypage?date=20150516"; //WILL NEED TO PULL TOMORROWS DATE AS DD-MM-YYY
    $html = curl($url);
    $dom  = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xpath                   = new DOMXPath($dom);
    //pull the individual cards for the day
    //li class="rac-cardsclass="ix ixc"
    $getdropdown             = '//div[contains(@data-location, "RACING_COUNTRY_GB_IE")]//div[contains(@class, "course")]';
    $getdropdown2            = $xpath->query($getdropdown);
    //loop through each individual card
    foreach($getdropdown2 as $dropresults) {
        //loop through and get all the a tags
        $arr = $dropresults->getElementsByTagName("a");
        foreach($arr as $item) {
            //only grab the links which point to the results page
            if(strpos($item->getAttribute('href'), 'raceresult') !== false) {
                //grab the code
                $code = explode("=", $item->getAttribute('href'));
                $code = end($code);
                $url  = "http://form.timeform.betfair.com/raceresult?raceId=" . $code; //WILL NEED TO PULL TOMORROWS DATE AS DD-MM-YYY
                $html = curl($url);
                $dom  = new DOMDocument();
                @$dom->loadHTML($html);
                $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
                $xpath                   = new DOMXPath($dom);
                $spanTexts               = array();
                //get the place name
                $getplacename            = '//span[contains(@class, "locality")]';
                $getplacename2           = $xpath->query($getplacename);
                //loop through each individual card
                foreach($getplacename2 as $getplacename22) {
                    echo "Venue: " . $venue = $getplacename22->textContent;
                } //$getplacename2 as $getplacename22
                $gettime  = '//abbr [contains(@class, "dtstart")]';
                //get the Date and the Time
                $gettime2 = $xpath->query($gettime);
                foreach($gettime2 as $gettime22) {
                    echo "Date : " . $Dateandtime = date(trim($gettime22->getAttribute('title')), strtotime('+5 hours'));
                } //$gettime2 as $gettime22
                //pull the data for the race e.g going money ect
                $getdropdown22  = '//div[contains(@class, "content")]/p';
                $getdropdown222 = $xpath->query($getdropdown22);
                foreach($getdropdown222 as $dropresults2) {

                 $racename = trim($dropresults2->childNodes->item(0)->textContent);

                    //foreach ($dropresults2->childNodes as $node) { if(is_object($node)) { echo $node->nodeType; } else { echo $node; } } 
                    foreach($dropresults2->childNodes as $node) {
                        if(is_object($node) && $node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE && strtolower($node->tagName) === 'span') {
                            $spanTexts[] = (string) $node->textContent;

                        } //is_object($node) && $node->nodeType === XML_ELEMENT_NODE && strtolower($node->tagName) === 'span'
                    } //$dropresults2->childNodes as $node
                    if(count($spanTexts) < 6)
                        continue;
                    list($going, $distance, $age, $prizemoney, $runners, $racetype) = $spanTexts;
                    $going      = str_replace(array(
                        'Â', 
                        'Going:',
                        '|'
                    ), '', $going);
                    $distance   = miletofurlong($distance = trim(GetBetween($distance, ':', 'Â')));
                    $age        = trim(GetBetween($age, ':', 'Â'));
                    $prizemoney = trim(GetBetween($prizemoney, '£', 'Â'));
                    $runners    = trim(GetBetween($runners, ':', 'Â'));
                    $racetype   = trim(GetBetween($racetype, ':', 'Â'));
                } //$getdropdown222 as $dropresults2
                //pull the individual horse data
                $getdropdown  = '//div[contains(@class, "table-container")]//tbody//tr';
                $getdropdown2 = $xpath->query($getdropdown);
                //loop through each individual card
                foreach($getdropdown2 as $dropresults) {
                    $position   = $dropresults->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent;
                    $draw       = str_replace(array('(',')'), '', $dropresults->childNodes->item(0)->childNodes->item(3)->textContent);
                    $losingdist = str_replace('Â', '', trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(2)->textContent));
                    if(strpos($losingdist, '¾') !== false) {
                        $losingdist = str_replace('¾', '.75', $losingdist);
                    } //strpos($losingdist, '¾') !== false
                    if(strpos($losingdist, '½') !== false) {
                        $losingdist = str_replace('½', '.5', $losingdist);
                    } //strpos($losingdist, '½') !== false
                    if(strpos($losingdist, '¼') !== false) {
                        $losingdist = str_replace('¼', '.25', $losingdist);
                    } //strpos($losingdist, '¼') !== false
                    $losingdist;
                    $horse    = trim(preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",str_replace("'","",trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(4)->textContent))));
                    $horseage = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(6)->textContent);
                    $weight   = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(8)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent);
                    $or       = str_replace(array('(',')'), '', trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(8)->childNodes->item(3)->textContent));
                    str_replace('-', '', $eq = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(10)->textContent));
                    $jockey              = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(12)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent);
                    $trainer             = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(12)->childNodes->item(4)->textContent);
                    $highandlowinrunning = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(14)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent);
                    $highandlow          = explode("/", $highandlowinrunning);
                    str_replace('-', '', $lowodds = trim($highandlow['1']));
                    str_replace('-', '', $highodds = trim($highandlow['0']));
                    $bfsp      = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(16)->childNodes->item(1)->textContent);
                    $isp       = trim(str_replace('/', '', $dropresults->childNodes->item(16)->childNodes->item(3)->textContent));
                    $placeodds = trim($dropresults->childNodes->item(18)->textContent);

     $venue = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,    $venue);
     $Dateandtime = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$Dateandtime);
     $going = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,    $going);
     $distance = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$distance);
     $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$age);
     $prizemoney = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$prizemoney);
     $runners = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$runners );
     $racetype = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$racetype);
     $position  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$position );
     $draw  = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$draw);
     $losingdist = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$losingdist);
     $horse = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$horse );
     $age = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$age);
     $weight = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$weight);
     $or = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$or );
     $eq = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$eq );
     $jockey = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$jockey);
     $trainer = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$trainer);
     $lowodds = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$lowodds);
     $highodds = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$highodds);
     $bfsp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$bfsp);
     $isp = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$isp);
     $placeodds = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,$placeodds);



     $sql = "
    INSERT INTO `Race_Records` 
    ( 
    `Venue`,
    `DateandTime`,
    `Going`,
    `Distance`,
    `Age`,
    `PrizeMoney`,
    `Runners`,
    `RaceType`,
    `Position`,
    `Draw`,
    `LosingDist`,
    `Horse`,
    `HorseAge`,
    `Weight`,
    `OR`,
    `EQ`,
    `Jockey`,
    `Trainer`,
    `InRunningLow`,
    `InRunningHigh`,
    `BFSP`,
    `ISP`,
    `PlaceOdds`,
    `RaceName`

    )
    VALUES
    ( 
    '$venue',
     '$Dateandtime',
     '$going', 
     '$distance', 
     '$age', 
     '$prizemoney',
     '$runners', 
     '$racetype',
     '$position',  
     '$draw',  
     '$losingdist', 
     '$horse', 
     '$age', 
     '$weight', 
     '$or', 
     '$eq', 
     '$jockey',
    '$trainer', 
    '$lowodds', 
     '$highodds', 
     '$bfsp',
     '$isp', 
     '$placeodds',  
     '$racename'
    )
    ";
     $res = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
      if (!$res) {
           echo PHP_EOL . "FAIL: $sql";
          trigger_error(mysqli_error($db), E_USER_ERROR);
       }




                } 
            } 
        } 
    } 



    $id = date_create($id);
    $theid2 = date_format($id,"d-m-Y");

      $url  = "www.sportinglife.com/racing/results/".$theid2; //WILL NEED TO PULL TOMORROWS DATE AS DD-MM-YYY
    $html = curl($url);
    $dom  = new DOMDocument();
    @$dom->loadHTML($html);
    $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
    $xpath                   = new DOMXPath($dom);

      $getdropdown             = '//li[contains(@class, "rac-cards")]//div[contains(@class, "ix ixv")]';
    $getdropdown2            = $xpath->query($getdropdown);
    //loop through each individual card
    foreach($getdropdown2 as $dropresults) {
        //loop through and get all the a tags
        $arr = $dropresults->getElementsByTagName("a");

        foreach($arr as $item) {
            //only grab the links which point to the results page
              //grab the code

               $getcomments =  $item->getAttribute('href');



        foreach ($listofcorses  as $bad) {
            if (strstr( strtolower($getcomments),strtolower($bad)) !== false) {






                $url  = "http://www.sportinglife.com/".$getcomments; //WILL NEED TO PULL TOMORROWS DATE AS DD-MM-YYY
                $html = curl($url);
                $dom  = new DOMDocument();
                @$dom->loadHTML($html);
                $dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
                $xpath                   = new DOMXPath($dom);
                $spanTexts               = array();
                //get the place name

                $getplacename            = '//table';
                $getplacename2           = $xpath->query($getplacename);
                //loop through each individual card
    $loopnumber = 0;
                foreach($getplacename2 as $getplacename22) {

              // get how many child nodes are in the loop
              $count = 0;
    foreach($getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(11)->childNodes as $node)    
      if(!($node instanceof \DomText))      
        $count++;

        //loop through and get the horses name and the comment

               for ($i = 0; $i < $count; $i++) {

                 if ($i % 2 == 0)
      {
       if ($getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(11)->childNodes->item($i)->childNodes->item(4) != null)
       {
           $horse = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim(preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z ]+/", "", preg_replace("/\([^\)]+\)/","",trim($getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(11)->childNodes->item($i)->childNodes->item(4)->textContent)))));
    $check = "ok";

           }
           else
           {
           $check = "no";
           }
      }
      else
      {

      if ($check == "ok") {
          $comments = mysqli_real_escape_string($db,trim($getplacename22 ->childNodes->item(11)->childNodes->item($i)->textContent));

          //update the database
        $results = $db->query("UPDATE Race_Records SET comments= '$comments' WHERE Horse='$horse'");

          }
      }
                     }
    }

                   }


                }

                }
                }

    ?>
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Current PHP version: 5.4.43

Comment: Are you running on apache or IIS?

Comment: apache is what it is running on

Comment: I assume PHP is not running safe mode as set_time_limit() will have no effect if it is: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: I used  echo  ini_get('max_execution_time'); and its set to 0

Answer (score 0):

You could try setting curl's timeout

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,1000);
```

You might also want to check that the services you are accessing in the loop are rate-limited or not, and if so put in an appropriate `sleep` in the loop to make sure you aren't making too many requests from the service in consecutive cycles; it could well be that the code is running OK, but then timeingout after a number of HTTP requests to the remote service

Comment: I tried this and it still times out.  what would i do with the sleep bit?

Comment: I would insert a sleep after each curl request, say sleep(1) to add  a 1 second pause. That would make your script take longer to run, but it would get round any potential timeout that curl is causing due to the target host timing out because of too many requests in quick succession.

Comment: BTW, are you running the script from a terminal, or accessing it via a web browser?

Comment: I just hacked your code to try and run it from a command line without your extra libs, and seems to run OK up until `foreach ($listofcorses  as $bad)` - i assume `$listofcorses` is included from one of the other files? The inital part of the code runs for me in under 20 seconds, so it may be an issue with the part after that.

Comment: Hey - yes list courses is just an array to only pull these race courses:  `$listofcorses            = array(
'Aintree',
'Ascot',

);`

Comment: Note more corses but i cant fit it in the comments

Comment: The code seems to be executing fast for me (41 seconds when going through all applicable racecourses), which would imply no rate limiting on the servers you are requesting.) I'm not executing your DB queries so it may be that they are the bottlneck. I'd recommend executing the script with output buffering disabled, or from a command line, to see try and indentify why point it times out for you.

Answer (score -1):

Set max execution time

```
// Begin your php code with this
ini_set('max_execution_time',300); // 60s*5=300s 5 minutes
```

Comment: Is that a crime to add a different method while question still open for answers?